# How to set ul/li attributes using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, attributes

```
<ul id="minorSelectBoxItOptions" class="selectboxit-options selectboxit-list" tabindex="-1" role="listbox" aria-hidden="true" style="min-width: 1350px; max-height: 139px; top: auto; display: none;">
    <li data-id="0" data-val="Status" data-disabled="false" class="selectboxit-option  selectboxit-option-first selectboxit-selected" role="option">
        <a class="selectboxit-option-anchor">
            <span class="selectboxit-option-icon-container">
                <i class="selectboxit-option-icon  selectboxit-container"></i>
            </span>Status123</a>
    </li>
    <li data-id="1" data-val="Status" data-disabled="false" class="selectboxit-option" role="option">
        <a class="selectboxit-option-anchor">
            <span class="selectboxit-option-icon-container">
                <i class="selectboxit-option-icon  selectboxit-container"></i>
            </span>Status456</a>
    </li>
    <li data-id="2" data-val="Individual" data-disabled="false" class="selectboxit-option selectboxit-focus" role="option" data-active="">
        <a class="selectboxit-option-anchor">
            <span class="selectboxit-option-icon-container">
                <i class="selectboxit-option-icon  selectboxit-container"></i>
            </span>Individual</a>
    </li>
    <li data-id="3" data-val="Minor" data-disabled="false" class="selectboxit-option  selectboxit-option-last" role="option">
        <a class="selectboxit-option-anchor">
            <span class="selectboxit-option-icon-container">
                <i class="selectboxit-option-icon  selectboxit-container"></i>
            </span>Minor</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

This is my  ul code. Here I have to select li value from JavaScript.

Suppose I have minor then through JavaScript I have to select ui-li as minor and I have to add `dataactive` attribute to minor li, and I have to add `class` value to that minor li.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$('li[data-val=Minor]').attr('dataactive',1).addClass('yourClass');
```